Can anyone debunk this claim regarding Non Hindus and other religion as per Hindu scriptures
I found this image online which contains references from Vedas and Puranas regarding disbelievers and blasphemers and how Hindu scriptures condemn them. Can anyone explain/debunk these claims?


Presently I am posting partial answer.

[Linga Purana II.11.35-37]
35.If people forsake Linga and begin to worship other deities they will go to the Raurava hell along with the king, their ruler.

If a king ceases to be a devotee of Siva and becomes attached to other Devas, it is like the behaviour of a young woman who
discarding her husband revels among her paramours.


The verse is talking about forsaking and ceasing to be a devotee. One can forsake to be a devotee only if he was a devotee earlier. It is basically saying one who got initiated into Siva folks shouldn't leave it. And it is also not talking about eternal hell for forsaking Siva.

[Skanda Purana III.ii.18.156-7]
She creates obstacles for a foolish one who does not worship. He will
have to witness death of the couple, destruction of wealth, great
fear, pain, sickness and incidents of arson. For this reason, O
Brāhmaṇas, an intelligent devotee should worship Mātaṅgī.

Not really talking anything about hell.

Padma Purana II.38 tells about how a heretic made the king Vena
unbeliever. In the chapter II.37 an heretic came and criticised Vedic practices pretty much. Those words are told by sages in retaliation of King Vena's act. He also said Jainism alone is the valid path. I am reproducing relevant verses;


O you very intelligent one, neither truth nor rite is seen in the
merciless Vedas and Brāhmaṇas and also in the brāhmaṇas who follow the
Vedas. O best king, the Vedas, void of truth are not Vedas and the
brāhmaṇas who are not truthful (are not brāhmaṇas). There is no fruit
of charity, so gifts also are not given. As are the characteristics of
śrāddha, same are those of charity. Whatever is the faith of Jīva is
the giver of enjoyment and salvation—that I shall tell you. First, one
with his mind being tranquil, should show kindness. One should
devoutly propitiate god Jina who (has pervaded) the mobile and
immobile. With one’s mind having pure thoughts, one should worship
Jina alone. Salutation should be offered to that god, and not
otherwise (i.e. not to anyone else). One should never salute the feet
of one’s mother and father.


Padma Purana 6.23.5-7:


If among hundred (pieces of any other kind of) wood, there is (just)
one (piece) of Tulasī-wood (in the funeral pyre), the man would have
salvation just at the time of cremation—even if he has committed a
crore of sins. By being sprinkled with the water of Gaṅgā, religious
merit becomes meritorious. (Pieces of) wood become meritorious (when)
mixed with Tulasī-wood.

Seriously, does this talk anything about Buddhism?

Matsya Purana Chapter 24:

The reason it quoted as false because as it opposed the Vedas, but still it can somehow lead a person to Moksha as discussed in this answer.. It also doesn't command about killing Buddhists, but how Indra killed sons of Brihaspati.

Vayu Purana Chapter 17 has only 7 verses, Brahmananda Purana reference is wrong.
Srimad Bhagavatam Book 2, CH 3 has only 25 verses.
Agni Purana 16.1-5 talks about deceiving Daityas ( a class of demons
as discussed before), not people.
Vishnu Purana 3.18 on speaking with infidel:


In consequence of the fault committed by Śatadhanu, by speaking to
an infidel when he was engaged in a solemn fast, he was born again
as a dog.

If you read carefully he talked with infidels at the time of fasting that's why he born as dog, not literally saying anything like one should never talk with infidel.

Vishnu Purana 3.17, Shiva Purana 2.5.4 talks about the story of how
Vishnu made Daityas led astray from the path of Vedas. Once there was
a fight between Devas and Daityas, Daityas were following the Vedas
so Devas cannot kill Daityas ( a class of demons). So Vishnu
incarnated as Buddha to make those Daityas move away from the path of
Vedas so that once they no longer follow Vedic path they could be
killed. It is not talking about killing any Buddhist who is living
today.
Shiva Purana II.5.6.28


O lord, favourably disposed towards your devotees, those Asuras have
resorted to Buddha’s religion and philosophy, thanks to our good
fortune and hence they have eschewed all Vedic sacred rites.

It is also talking about a story similar to Devas and Daityas mentioned in the previous verse.

Srimad Bhagavatam 5.26.14-15 talks about punishment in temporary hell for those who deviate from the Vedic path not really anything about killing.

Devi Bhagavatam 11.1.25-37 doesn't really talk about Buddhas, it is added by the translator. It actually says:



Those who do injury to others even by the blade of a Kus'a grass used
as a weapon, go to hell with their heads downwards and their feet
upwards. Those that follow their own sweet free will, that take up any
sort of dress (e. g. Bauddhas), those that follow the philosophical
doctrines called Pâs'upatas,

It clearly condemns causing injuries to others.

Kurma Purana I.12 has only 23 verses, Mahabharata reference is also wrong.
Brahmadvish of Rig Veda 2.12.6, 2.23.4 refers to Rakshasas.


उद वर्ह रक्षः सहमूलमिन्द्र वर्श्चा मध्यं परत्यग्रंश्र्णीहि | आ
कीवतः सललूकं चकर्थ बरह्मद्विषे तपुषिं हेतिमस्य || (Rig Veda
3.30.17)
Meaning: Pluck up the Raksasas, Indra, by the root; cut as under
the middle, blight the summit: to whatever remote (regions) you have
driven the sinner, cast upon the enemy of the Veda you consuming
weapon.

Rakshasas flew after transforming into birds, so not referring to any human as Rakshasas:

[Rig Veda 7.104.18]
“Spread out, ye Maruts, search among the people: seize ye and grind
the Raksasas to pieces, Who fly abroad,
transformed to birds, at night-time, or sully and pollute our holy
worship.”


In Rig Veda 9.13.9, 9.63.5, it is mentioned that Soma destroys
अराव्णः. In Rig Veda 8.60.10, Rakshasas are associated with अराव्णः.
Sayanacharya commented that अराव्णः means one who doesn't bring
gifts.


[Rig Veda 8.60.10]
पाहि विश्वस्माद्रक्षसो अराव्णः प्र स्म वाजेषु नोऽव ।
त्वामिद्धि
नेदिष्ठं देवतातय आपिं नक्षामहे वृधे ॥
Protect us from every impious rākṣasa, shield us in battles; we
approach you, our nearest neighbour,our kinsman, for sacrifice and for
increase.”

Sayana comments:

Impious: not giving (sacrificial) gifts


Rig Veda 7.6.3 talks about destroying Panis and Dasyus. Panis are
class of demons and Dasyus in Vedas are 50 children of Vishvamitra.


नयक्रतून गरथिनो मर्ध्रवाचः पणीन्रश्रद्धानव्र्धानयज्ञान |
पर-पर तान
दस्यून्रग्निर्विवाय पूर्वश्चकारापरानयज्यून ||   Rig Veda 7.6.3
The foolish, faithless, rudely-speaking niggards, without belief or
sacrifice or worship,-Far far sway hath Agni chased those Dasyus, and,
in the cast, hath turned the godless westward.


Even if you mean those unbelievers in Vedic verses are referring to humans, they don't really commanding hindus to kill unbelievers. They either describe how god killed unbelievers or a prayer to destroy those unbelievers.

Rig Veda 6.14.3, 3.53.14, 20.93.2 talk about either Dasyus or Panis.



[Rig Veda 1.18.9]
I have seen Narāśaṁsa, him most resolute, most widely famed, As ’twere
the Household Priest of heaven.

Does it talk anything about plundering?

Atharva Veda 5.20.4-5: verses are addressed to war drum. War drums cannot physically go and seize or capture anything. It should be understood that these words are specifically chanted to get victory in wars as drums cannot do those things in reality.


Victorious in the battle, loudly roaring, seizing what may be
seized, look all around thee.   Utter, O Drum, thy heavenly voice with triumph. Bring, as a priest, our enemies' possessions.
Hearing the Drum's far-reaching voice resounding, let the foe's    dame, waked by the roar, afflicted, Grasping her son, run forward in her terror amid the conflict of the deadly weapons.

The verses are addressed to war drum, and this is a hymn to secure victory in war. It is saying that the drum should cause extreme fear (terror here denotes extreme fear) in the enemy's wife that she should grasp her son and run away.

Atharva Veda 10th book has only 10 hymns, so how 118th hymn came?

- Atharva Veda 11.2.21

Do not covet our cattle, our men, our goats and sheep! Bend thy
course elsewhere, O strong god (ugra), slay the offspring of the
blasphemers!

The word used here is पियारु (piyAru) which is translated as blasphemers by Maurice bloomfield. It means censuring/mocking/overbearing. It is not talking about enemies. So one who censures/mocks his children should be destroyed, but wait it not commanding us to kill children of those who censure us, but a prayer verse to Bhava, Sarva, Rudra to do so.
